# Remove provided elements form given array and return the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove unknown number of given elements from a given array. The function `removeFromArray` must have 1st argument as the given array and sequential arguments as the elements to be removed and must return the array with given elements removed.

I have tried the following code:

```
 const removeFromArray = function(givenArray, ...elementsToBeRemoved) {

for(i=0;i<=givenArray.length-1;i++){
    
        elementsToBeRemoved.forEach(value =>{
            if(givenArray[i]===value){
                givenArray.splice(givenArray.indexOf(value),1);
            }
            
        })
        
    
}
    return givenArray; 
};
```

As you can see my function takes 1st argument as `givenArray` and then it takes second argument `...elementsToBeRemoved` as a rest parameter. I then run a loop from 0 to the second-last element in the `givenArray`. Inside the loop, I apply the `forEach` method to the rest parameter which skims through each value of the parameter. I then apply an if conditional inside the `forEach` method which checks whether the element with current index `givenArray[i]` is equal to the current value of the rest parameter. If this condition is fulfilled then I use the `splice` method on the given array and pass index of the value to be removed from array and 1 as the number of items to be removed as second parameter.

My code works on the most part but doesn't work in the following case"

```
removeFromArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],1,2,3,4);
```

returns [ 5, 6, 7 ] as expected but

```
removeFromArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],4,3,2,1);
```

returns [ 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]

but it should have returned [ 5, 6, 7 ] as before.

Comment: maybe `sort()` the arguments first?

Comment: forEach won't update itself and when you delete some things move left and sneak under. Trying for(i=givenArray.length()-1;i>=0;i--){ is better, but I think that's not right either, things could match off different parts, better to reverse the nesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues with moving targets. If you start at the left of the array and you delete, for each does not update, and you don't end up looking at everything because things sneak to where you just checked. Also, if you delete immediately when one character matches, you're not checking for the next thing, which maybe does not matter if you fix the first issue. I think the below simplifies things by working from the right and checking all the characters first before modifying what you are looking at.

```
  const removeFromArray = function(givenArray, ...elementsToBeRemoved) {

for(let i=givenArray.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        let needDelete = false; 
        elementsToBeRemoved.forEach(value =>{
            if(givenArray[i]===value){
               needDelete = true; 
            }})
            if (needDelete){
            givenArray.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
        
    return givenArray;
}
```